# Concise guide to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a very concise guide to using rails. I've done lots of work with other similar frameworks like Django so I just need a very short tutorial. Does anything like that exist?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you think to try the [official website](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)?

Comment: Yeah I did think of that but I was wondering if anybody knew of anything that was less of a full documentation of the whole system and more just a cheat sheet or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is best guide for those who are new to rails..

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to put up with a few quick video tutorials, Rails for Zombies by EnvyLabs ([railsforzombies.org](http://railsforzombies.org)) gives a good overview of the framework.

If you decide to check it out, know this: at the time of this writing, there's one error in the tutorials. The code they show you for writing a basic redirect is missing a prepended slash on the URI. (At least, according to the interpreter they use for the accompanying exercises, it's incorrect.)

Other than that small gripe, in my opinion it's a great way to onboard yourself and colleagues in Rails, before drilling down into the gritty details.